# Find if value is present in list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find if 2 is present in `a`, but when I run the code it says its not here

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2]

if b in a:
    print('its here')
else:
    print('its not here')
```

From what I read online I see `in` operator used to check if a value is in an array.
although if I use: `if 2 in a:` then It shows as its here but I would like b to do that.

Comment: You can check if an element is in an array, but you cannot check whether an array is part of another array. Try using set notation and the intersection here.

Comment: `a` doesn't contain `b` since `b` is a list itself. Your code currently checks if the list `[2]` is contained withing `[1, 2, 3]`, which is `False`. If you set `b = 2`, your program should output 'its here'.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo unless you are specifically asking how to check if all elements in one list are in another

Answer (score 0):

You are searching `a` for a list containing 2, not for the value 2 itself. (`b` is a list not a value)

You could get it to work by using the first element of the `b`:

```
if b[0] in a:
    print('its here')
else:
    print('its not here')
```

Or you could check if all values of list `b` are present in list `a`

```
if all(value in a for value in b):
    print('its here')
else:
    print('its not here')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the for loop to check if the b is in a or vice versa.

Here I made a example like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2]

for x in a, b:
    if x == b:
        print("b is in a")
    else:
        print("b is not in a")
```

Now over the print you can put the text you want, like "B is here".

Comment: This answer isn't even syntactically correct.

Comment: Did you mean to write `in zip(a, b)`? In any case, `all(x in a for x in b)` would be better

Comment: ... nor does it address OP’s question.